# Call another appllication from my application

Tags: android, cordova

I am creating an application where I need to call another application that is already installed in the device on button click.

I have done some research on it and I understand that I will need to call an intent for the same. What I dont understand is I do not have a class name for the application I want to call. For example, if I want to call the device's gallery from my application on button click, how do I do that?

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/");
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(uri);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivity(intent);
return true;
```

Thanks guys. I have tried this code but it said document could not be opened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the exact application is less important, and you just need something that will display your content, you can omit the component name entirely, too.  Just set the action, data, and (optionally) type on the intent and let the OS do the work.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(/*your data uri*/);
intent.setType(/*your data's MIME type*/);
startActivity(intent);
```

This intent will be handled by some app that has registered for intents with the view action and the appropriate MIME type.  This is an implicit intent, like Adil mentioned.

Comment: i have an application called printershare which i need to open from my application. Can you provide me the uri to open that??? I think I am missing out on the correct URI..

Comment: If it's an application that you didn't write, you should check the printershare documentation. No way to really guess the package or class names. In general, you probably can't assume that printershare is installed either.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to call [Implicit Intents](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ires)

From the documentation:

> **Implicit Intents** have not specified a component; instead, they must
>   include enough information for the system to determine which of the
>   available components is best to run for that intent.

These intents can be triggered providing any **action**, **type** or **category** information

**For example** you want to open browser `Activity` and you don't know the `Activity` class name you will use something like this:

```
Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.google.com"));
startActivity(in);
```

**Another example**: you don't know the `Gallery Activity` class, you will call it using `Implicit Intent` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Select Picture"), SELECT_PICTURE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the call 
Enjoy coding....

```
    Intent res = new Intent();
    String mPackage = "com.ReachOut";
    String mClass = ".splash1";
    res.setComponent(new ComponentName(mPackage,mPackage+mClass));
    startActivity(res);
```

Comment: "What i dont understand is I do not have a class name for the application I wanna call" is what the author says. So he/she can't really enjoy coding with this!