# How to get the Activity or Activity name of the Home Screen of Phone in android?

Tags: android

How can i know the Activity name of the Home(Launcher) Screen. I am getting the intent using the below code:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
   startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the `Intent` with providing `Action` and `Categories` don't need to know the name of `Activity` class. (these type of [Intents are called Implicit Intents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8799515/593709))

Name of `Activity` are not revealed to the public.

However Android is open source, you can know the `Activity` name of [Home Screen](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#cZwlSNS7aEw/packages/apps/Launcher2/src/com/android/launcher2/Launcher.java&q=Launcher&exact_package=android&type=cs).

Comment: But how can i know that activity name in the above link??

Answer (score 0):

Check for the given below code, hope you are looking for this.

```
String myActivityName = (String) getTitle();
```

myActivityName will be your activity name what you have set through manifest or through setTitle().

Comment: My intention is to change the brightness of the Launcher screen from my service class. To change the brightness i will use window manager.   WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
  lp.screenBrightness = brightness;
  getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

Comment: So this getWindow() only works for Activity. So i need the Activity instance of the Launcher Screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try Eclipse with ADT-Plugins: 
`Window - Show View - Android - Windows` (not working on every device - must be debugable)